# "let" vs "const" vs "var" vs "state" in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React.js recently,

and I have some questions,

1. As we know setState is asynchrony, if we don't use js framework, we will use let const or var to setting variable, it's synchrony, but why we should much more use state instead of let const var to setting variable in React.js?
2. Some scenario I use state but it cannot work very well to my WebApp, so that I try to use let to set my variable, and it can work very well, but I think if I use let rather than state, is it not a good idea because I wasted React.js advantage?

thank you for your help :>

Comment: Normal variables defined using `let`, `const` and `var` won't be saved between renders and won't trigger a new render when changed.

Comment: Changing variables instead of state does not re-render the component.

Comment: This question relates to JS (specifically ECMASCRIPT6) not ReactJS. Check the link  for details. https://www.developer.com/languages/javascript/javascript-var-let-const-variable-declaration/

Comment: also the documentation linked in the comments of the duplicate is very relevant: [Step 3: Identify The Minimal (but complete) Representation Of UI State](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think changing variables will not re-render the component is very useful, when I see this comment, I understand. Thank U

Answer (score 0):

Simply, in most cases we use `state` if we will use it in the UI ( in the JSX mockups ), as when it updates with `setState` the UI updates, this doesn't happen with normal javascript variables as it re-initializes when the component updates.

That's besides that other hooks, just updates regard to stateful dependencies only, like `useEffect`, `useMemo`, `useCallback`.